# Issue After SP1 2013 update

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am facing a issue, we have created some customized list forms using jQuery in 2013 which takes the data from mandatory field (e.g : Title) and then performs some operation, we were able to read its value before the update.

but now while reading it gives undefined, any help will be appreciated.

let me know if any more information is required.

code:

```
var docname = $("input[title='Display Name']").val()+$("input[title='Display Name']").parent().text();
```

Comment: You're second Display Name includes a space after the text. Intentional or a typo?

Comment: sorry added while putting the question here, it is ok in the file

Comment: Use developer tools to inspect the element.

Comment: yes i tried with it, but same issue is there

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue where the field `'required'` was changed to the local language name. In Swedish `'obligatorisk'`. We had to change the JavaScript looking for the local language instead.

Comment: i have only english language and no variations, its a very simple site.